# How to delete the file?

Tags: linux, ubuntu

```
root@ubuntu:/home/tomxue/SourceCode_Windows/linux-stable/.git/objects/pack# cat tmp_pack_rjkmke 
cat: tmp_pack_rjkmke: Permission denied
root@ubuntu:/home/tomxue/SourceCode_Windows/linux-stable/.git/objects/pack# ls -al
ls: cannot access tmp_pack_rjkmke: Permission denied
total 0
drwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Nov 16 16:47 .
drwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Nov 16 16:56 ..
-????????? ? ?    ?    ?            ? tmp_pack_rjkmke
root@ubuntu:/home/tomxue/SourceCode_Windows/linux-stable/.git/objects/pack# touch tmp_pack_rjkmke 
touch: cannot touch ‘tmp_pack_rjkmke’: Permission denied
root@ubuntu:/home/tomxue/SourceCode_Windows/linux-stable/.git/objects/pack# rm tmp_pack_rjkmke 
rm: cannot remove ‘tmp_pack_rjkmke’: Permission denied
root@ubuntu:/home/tomxue/SourceCode_Windows/linux-stable/.git/objects/pack# rm -rf tmp_pack_rjkmke 
rm: cannot remove ‘tmp_pack_rjkmke’: Permission denied
```

As you can see, the file's access info contains a lot of "?". And I cannot even `touch` it, neither can I delete it. How to do then?

Comment: How is this a programming question? It belongs on either unix.stackexchange.com or serverfault.com.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Reboot and try again
2. Make a file system check and try again (preferrably booting from CD/USB, I like [SystemRescueCD](http://www.sysresccd.org/SystemRescueCd_Homepage))